# C9.IO - Debugging Failed - Failed to open socket on port 15400, waiting 1000 ms before retrying

Tags: node.js, debugging, port

The code in C9.IO it's...

```
var http = require("http");
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.end("Hello world from Cloud9!");
}).listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP);
```

The result at debug...

```
Your code is running at 'http://demo-project.gerardogrimaldi.c9.io'.
```

Important: use 'process.env.PORT' as the port and 'process.env.IP' as the host in your scripts!
debugger listening on port 15400
Failed to open socket on port 15400, waiting 1000 ms before retrying
Failed to open socket on port 15400, waiting 1000 ms before retrying
Failed to open socket on port 15400, waiting 1000 ms before retrying
Failed to open socket on port 15400, waiting 1000 ms before retrying
Failed to open socket on port 15400, waiting 1000 ms before retrying

Like this forever, this problem it's being sinnce the last week. I don't know what to do the C9.IO support people it's usless the dont have any idea...

I have reset the workspace, the account, i'm lost...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below steps should be able to work around this issue: 
1. netstat -tulpn | grep :15400 
2. Find the PID and run kill PID 
More details can be found at http://gudutalk.wordpress.com/2014/03/24/c9-io-debugging-failed-failed-to-open-socket-on-port-15400/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an older process is already running . You have to kill the older process yourself.

See the solution posted here : https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9/issues/2170.

Answer (score 1):

I have the similar problem and when I kill the PID it is still in a list of process. 
So I make kill $(ps ax | grep '[j]s' | awk '{ print $1 }')  as discribed here  http://support.cloud9ide.com/entries/22913232-Error-listen-EADDRINUSE  or

1. netstat -tulpn | grep :15400
2. Find the PID and run kill PID

in any case one js debug process exists in list of process, which I see using ps ax command in terminal